# Evaluating $\displaystyle\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{-xu^{2}+yu+z}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This integral is just a step in a much longer problem for physics, but I am having some trouble with it.

> $$\int\frac{ \mathrm du}{\sqrt{-xu^{2}+yu+z}}$$

$x$, $y$ , and $z$ are constants

Also if the $-$ sign  in front of the first term is an issue (or any of the signs in front of any of the constants for that matter), I can easily fix that, as most of the function constants are just "dummy" placeholders for other terms.

Comment: Step 1: complete square.  Step 2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Comment: The details will depend on the exact values of the parameters $x$, $y$, $z$. On the assumption $x$ is positive, most of the time by completing the square we get an arcsine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note the question says signs does not really matter here!

---

> $$I=\int\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{-xu^{2}+yu+z}}=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}}$$

Using Euler Substitution
$$\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}=x\sqrt a+t\iff x=\frac{c-t^2}{2t\sqrt a-b}=\iff \mathrm dx=-\frac{2(\sqrt a(c+t^2)-bt)}{(2t\sqrt a-b)^2}\mathrm dt$$

---

$$\begin{align}I&=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}}\\
&=\int\frac{1}{\left({t+\sqrt a\dfrac{(c-t^2)}{2t\sqrt a-b}}\right)}\cdot\left(-\frac{2(\sqrt a(c+t^2)-bt)}{(2t\sqrt a-b)^2}\right)\mathrm dt\tag{1}\\
&=\int\frac{2}{b-2t\sqrt a}\mathrm dt\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\ln\Big(b-2t\sqrt a\Big)+C\tag{3}\\
I&=\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\ln\left[b-2\sqrt a\Big(\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}-x\sqrt{a}\Big)\right]+C\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

> [$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\ln\left[b-2\sqrt a\Big(\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}-x\sqrt{a}\Big)\right]+C$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+-%281%29%2F%28sqrt+%28a%29%29ln%28b-2sqrt+%28a%29%28sqrt%28ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%29-xsqrt%28a%29%29)

---

$\text{Explanations}\\ 1.\text{ Euler Substitution}\\
2. \text{ Magic }\\
3. \text{ Integrating (2) }\\
4. \text{ Putting Everything back }$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Complete the square under the radical so that its argument looks something like $(x+a)^2 + c$ for some $a, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

At that point, you can finish up with a trig substitution.